# Is my Vista Ultimate 64 bit license invalid for an upgrade from Vista 32 bit Home Premium?

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade

I brought an upgrade disk for Windows Vista Ultimate 64 bit. I want to upgrade my Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit to that. Now I am having activation issues. So I rang up Microsoft, the girl answering my phone, after a long while told me that I can't upgrade from Windows Vista Home Premium 32 bit to Ultimate 64 bit, and that my license is invalid.

But my understanding was that I can't do an in place upgrade where I get to keep all my settings. I can upgrade but I have to do a clean install where I won't be able to keep my previous settings.

Am I right or is the license I purchased invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The license you purchased is valid
- You however, **cannot** do an inplace upgrade, from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system, you will need to do a complete reinstall.

This has been [documented by Microsoft:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/32-bit-and-64-bit-Windows-frequently-asked-questions)

> Can I upgrade from a 32-bit version of
>   Windows to a 64-bit version of
>   Windows?
>
> No. If you are currently running a
>   32-bit version of Windows, you can
>   only perform an upgrade to another
>   32-bit version of Windows. Similarly,
>   if you are running a 64-bit version of
>   Windows Vista, you can only perform an
>   upgrade to another 64-bit version of
>   Windows Vista.

To ease the process, however, I think you can make use of [Windows Easy Transfer](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/features/easy-transfer.aspx)

> Windows Easy Transfer is a wizard that
>   helps you transfer the data that is
>   important to you, including:
>
> - User accounts
> - Files and folders
> - Program data files and settings
> - E-mail messages, settings, and contacts
> - Photos, music, and videos
> - Windows settings
> - Internet settings
>
>   **Programs (applications) are not
>     transferred**